# How to translate this query into linq?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I have this SQL query

```
SELECT TOP 1 
    DOCID, ACTOR_ID, ACTOR_ROLE, ACTION_ID 
FROM
    ex_DOCAction 
WHERE
    DOCID = 126251
GROUP BY
    DOCID, ACTOR_ROLE, ACTION_ID, ACTOR_ID
HAVING
    COUNT(ACTION_ID) = 1
```

I came up with this:

```
from x in _db.ex_DOCAction.Where(a => a.DOCID == request.DocId)
group x by new { x.DOCID, x.ACTOR_ROLE, x.ACTION_ID, x.ACTOR_ID } into grouped
where
```

and I don't know how to translate

```
 HAVING COUNT(ACTION_ID) = 1
```

There are lots of similar questions here, but I didn't find any question where `count()` had a parameter.

Comment: The parameter in COUNT doesn't matter. It just counts all occurrences,  distinct or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you can't translate that group by + uniqueness check directly into SQL.
You can return a structure, where you calculate the amount of the unique `Action_Id`s

```
from x in _db.ex_DOCAction.Where(a => a.DOCID == request.DocId)
  group x by new { x.DOCID, x.ACTOR_ROLE, x.ACTION_ID, x.ACTOR_ID }
    into grouped
  select new {Key = grouped.Key, Count = (from y in grouped select y.ACTION_ID).Distinct().Count() };
```

Comment: wouldn't it just check if sum of all actionid values is equal to one?

Comment: To be honest I don't know the type of the `action_id`. So maybe that's a wrong approach. Can you tell me what is the type of the `action_id`

Comment: it's nullable int, but anyway, this query checks if grouped result has unique actionid and returns it. your query will group, then add actionids and check if their sum is equal to 1

Comment: According to my knowledge there is no such linq operator that can be used in **Linq2Sql** where you can express that one easily

Answer (score 0):

A Group by create a two dimensional list : List>.  To Top is the first member of List.  See code below

```
var results = _db.ex_DOCAction
   .Where(a => (a.DOCID == request.DocId) && (a.ACTION_ID != null))
   .GroupBy(x => new { x.DOCID, x.ACTOR_ROLE, x.ACTION_ID, x.ACTOR_ID })
   .Select(x => x.First())
   .ToList();
```